# JavaScript - Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I have an error in JS:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

The line with error is the second one:

```
 var link = $('.nav').find('li.active:not(.dropdown)').find('a');
 var params = link.attr('href').split('/').filter(Boolean).slice(0, 3);
```

Comment: That means the `a` element doesn't have an `href` attribute. So you are either looking for the wrong `a` element or you have to take into account that not every `a` element has an `href` attribute. Can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: So `.attr('href')` returns `undefined` -> https://api.jquery.com/attr/ -> _"As of jQuery 1.6, the `.attr()` method returns `undefined` **for attributes that have not been set**."_

Comment: It could also mean that any of the previous items were not found (e.g., '.nav', 'li.active:not(.dropdown)', 'a'). jQuery does not throw errors when it can't find things; it just returns a jQuery object with zero elements.

Comment: You might want to check for link.attr('href') to not return falsey before you do something:
`if (link.attr('href')) { //do something }`

Comment: @Heretic Monkey Wouldn't there be an error already when you try to call .attr() on link if it would be empty?

Comment: @Chaz Simple answer: try it :) run `jQuery("nonsense").attr('href')`. It won't throw an error, even though the query "nonsense" returns an empty result. It just returns `undefined`.

Comment: Link is ok;
thanks for help :)

Comment: One more thing: maybe you know how to add an additional condition to the link that also filters by class name